# How do I handle the issue about ContentSecurityPolicyFilterTest Fail during maven install for hawtio?

Tags: hawtio

all.

I am a starter for hawtio.
I tried to build the source for hawtio by downloading it from github.
But, I found exception during test for maven install.

```
 ## Building

After you've cloned hawtio's git repo the first thing you should do is build the whole project.     First `cd` into the root directory of the hawtio project and run:

     mvn clean install

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Test set: io.hawt.web.filters.ContentSecurityPolicyFilterTest
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019 s <<< FAILURE! - in  io.hawt.web.filters.ContentSecurityPolicyFilterTest
```

How do I handle that this issue is fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the details of the test errors?  I ran the same test on hawtio master but it passed ok. Probably it's specific to some env or java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used hawtio before and I think this error is more towards the server certificates being absent for one of the servers that are configured in the test case.

More infor from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) -

> Content Security Policy (CSP) is an added layer of security that helps
>   to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site
>   Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks. These attacks are used for
>   everything from data theft to site defacement to distribution of
>   malware.

This is related to an HTTP header used for security. I am not aware of the exact solution for this but, if you want to proceed without it, you can skip the test until you get the solution by using -

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Since it is related to security it is **always** better to fix them. You can go to the test case code, find the DNS hostname and add its certificates into your JDK and run.